# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in testing django constraints

Tags: django

I want to test this constraint in django who include a condition check birth_date field that must be little than "2011-00-00"
but when i run `python3 manage.py test`  i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dd\Desktop\Dev\django\lemoon\lemoon\account\tests.py", line 45, in test_create_user_under_10
    self.assertRaises(IntegrityError,user.save())
  File "c:\users\dd\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 733, in assertRaises
    return context.handle('assertRaises', args, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\dd\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 201, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from .managers import UserManager
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120,unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True 

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin 

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(name="email_user_idx",fields=['email'])
        ]
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(name="check_birth_date",check=models.Q(birth_date__lte="2011-00-00")) 
        ]
```

tests.py:

```py
class Test(TestCase):

    def test_create_user_under_10(self):

            User = get_user_model()
            user = User.objects.test_under_age(email="majid@email.com",first_name="small_majid",
            last_name="majidi",birth_date="2011-05-22",password="mybestpassword")

            self.assertRaises(IntegrityError,user.save())
```

please correct me if i wrote my tests in bad form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `assertRaises` method the wrong way, you should implement this with a *context manager*:

```
class Test(TestCase):

    def test_create_user_under_10(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.test_under_age(email='majid@email.com', first_name='small_majid',
        last_name='majidi',birth_date='2011-05-22',password='mybestpassword')
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            user.save()
```

In this case however it seems to fail because your `user.save()` returns `None`, and thus does not raises an error. Not all databases implement constraint checks, and furthermore `2011-00-00` does not look like a valid date.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and i must change `2011-00-00` to `2011-01-01` to have correct form